# Converting a xcodeproj in-app purchase to a pkg file from terminal (Bash) or how to convert a xcarchive file to a pkg file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am trying to create a bash script to automate the creation of in-app purchase pkg files.

I am at a point that the script creates successfully all in-app purchase xcodeproj projects and then archive them using this command

```
xcodebuild -scheme $nameOfProject archive
```

**$nameOfProject** is a variable that holds, inside a loop, the name of the xcodeproj file correspondent to the in-app purchase.

After doing this, I have to open the archive part of Xcode and manually export all archives to create the pkg files that I need to have to upload to iTC.

Is there any command that I can use to do this automatically from terminal?

Another thing that would provide the same solution would be: how to convert a xcarchive file into a pkg file?

Comment: I have read the accepted answer, but I can't manage to make it work. Could you please provide me with your bash script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some googling and some testing with the "In-app purchase content" Project, I think that what you need to use is the `productbuild` command line tool. Since I am only iOS developer myself, I have no experience with creating installers but I am pretty sure the "pkg" file for the in-app content is created using this command line tools.

To find the correct parameters you can refer to
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/DistributingApplications/DistributingApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH5-SW1

or `man`.

**Edit:**
To test what XCode does, I have created a simple project
[image: Project]

And I archived it:
[image: Archive contents]

Then I created a simple program, let's call it `ArgumentLogger`, the code is

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    //Open a file for logging 
    FILE* file = fopen("/Users/Sulthan/Desktop/log.txt","a+");

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        //log all parameters
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", argv[i]);
    }

    //end
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Let's have an example - for bash command:

```
ArgumentLoggger --arg test1 test2 test3
```

`log.txt` will contain

```
ArgumentLogger
--arg
test1
test2
test3
```

Now, let's replace `/usr/bin/productbuild` with this program

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/productbuild /usr/bin/productbuild_old
sudo mv ArgumentLogger /usr/bin/productbuild
```

and then hit "Distribute" in XCode.
[image: Distribute]
and export the package.

`log.txt` now contains

```
/usr/bin/productbuild
--content
/var/folders/v5/wwrmfpqx2mx1q5sf67_6vgg00000gn/T/FDCEA38E-1EF6-490B-8C30-8B0675C56CC8-47322-00014822C462D3CD/TestContent
/var/folders/v5/wwrmfpqx2mx1q5sf67_6vgg00000gn/T/FDCEA38E-1EF6-490B-8C30-8B0675C56CC8-47322-00014822C462D3CD/TestContent.pkg
```

Now we see exactly what XCode did.

The second file is the resulting file, I am not sure whether there is something more done with the file or not, but after expanding it with `pkgutil`, the contents seem to be the same as the ones in the `pkg` created from XCode.

The first file is a directory which seems to be taken directly from the `xcarchive` file.
Let's see its contents
[image: Temp dir contents]

**Edit 2:**
In summary, the `bash` script should be something along the lines of:

```
CONTENTS_DIR = $( find "$nameOfProject.xcarchive" -name "InAppPurchaseContent" -type d )
PKG_FILE = "$nameOfProject.pkg"

productbuild --content "$CONTENTS_DIR" "$PKG_FILE"
```

Comment: after checking that out I see this uses an app to create a pkg. In-app purchases are just structures without any app. Use Xcode to create a new project of the king iOS > in-app purchase and see what you have. Every in-app has to generate each one pkg.

Comment: A `pkg` can have arbitrary contents. You don't need an application to create an installer, you can package any files. On MacOS, an app is basically just a folder. You can inspect the `pkg` using `pkgutil` and experiment with the parameters a bit.

Comment: @RubberDuck Experimented a bit more and extended the answer.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. When I archive an in-app purchase project (.xcodeproj) from the bash script using "xcodebuild -scheme projectName archive" it creates a xcarchive file that has just [this structure](http://imgur.com/kd6tVBw), nothing more. I don't see the files you mention.... if xcodebuild is not the one to use, I don't see a command line for productbuild that can create the xcarchive. Also see if your pkg has the structure I mention on this answer.

Comment: @RubberDuck XCode first takes the contents from .xcarchive file and copies them to a tmp directory. Then it runs `productbuild`, giving it the tmp directory as a parameter and target .pkg file path (also in tmp). As the last step it moves the .pkg from tmp to the target path you specified. It's that simple. My answer just documents all the steps I took to understand the process.

Comment: I don't know how you discovered that, but I am impressed. For the 100 point question point :) do you know the command line Xcode uses with productbuild to create the pkg?

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes, I replaced `productbuild` with my own program logging the parameters. Read my answer again :)

Comment: you keep saying I replaced productbuild... replaced where??? Your program opens a txt file... what txt is that? Sorry, this whole thing is very cloudy. Please tell me the steps I need to follow to create the pkg from the xcarchive or from the xcodeproj.

Comment: @RubberDuck Added a summary, you can test it out.

Comment: Oh YEAH!!!!!!!!! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  That's it! You deserve the points. Can you tell me how you discovered the processes taken by Xcode?

Comment: @RubberDuck Extended the answer. Don't know how to put it more simply... Also made a small fix in the bash script.

Comment: I think that this can be done by simply creating the directory structure with the plist and the contents directory. No need at all to create the xcarchive in the first place. Thanks for the solution, but you did not answer how you discovered how Xcode was doing it. 

Comment: @RubberDuck My answer lists all the steps I did to discover it. Yes, you are right you don't really need to archive, you don't even need the xcode project.