# How to create a hosted content package without Xcode?

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase

I was wondering if there is any other way to create a hosted content package for an in-app purchase without using X-Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a terminal to do so, and we even don't need to create an in-app purchase using Xcode. Here are the steps.

1- Create a folder, let's call it "zzz"
2- Add your .plist file similar to the .plist file which the in-app purchase project created from Xcode would have generated, make sure to update the version and the product identifier fields.
3- Create a contents folder inside of it, and in the contents folder place your in-app purchase contents.
4- Open your terminal and write

```
productbuild --content "zzz" "zzz/nameOfPackage.pkg"
```

so basically after --content you write the full path of your folder, then the full path of where you want you package to be and the name of package.

I used this answer as reference [Converting a xcodeproj in-app purchase to a pkg file from terminal (Bash) or how to convert a xcarchive file to a pkg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688990/converting-a-xcodeproj-in-app-purchase-to-a-pkg-file-from-terminal-bash-or-how)

Answer (score 0):

if you're referring to having a content bundle (i.e. a .zip file) with contents pertaining to your app, then yes.

I refer to the App Store Review Guidelines here from Apple themselves: (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

- IN terms of functionality, if the bundle downloads code in any way or form, your app will be rejected (Apple guidelines 2.7).

That's the main one that's mentions. Other than that, there's the general guidelines mentioned as per their website...

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I have an in-app purchase product and I was to host its content on Apple's server to do that I need to upload a package of my product content (say a ringtone) to creat a package of that ringtone I need to use Xcode, I was wondering if there's another way without using Xcode

Comment: The only round-about way I would know if is using third party scripts and tools i.e. the `xcodeproj` ruby gem, amongst other things. In regards to the legality of doing that, I can't comment. I'm not too sure how Apple would react to that...

Comment: I found a way using the terminal, I have added my finding as an answer. Thanks for trying to help =)

Comment: Be warned though, if Xcode isn't installed this won't work if Xcode and/or the OSX 10.x toolchains aren't installed. pkgbuild and product build are both part of the CommandLineTools

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks again